# How to write into csv like table

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Here is my code in Python:

```
with open('my.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(('Users','Date','Location'))
 for row in my_dict.items():
     writer.writerow(row)
```

The output of my CSV is like below:

screenshot of current table

[image]

So, how I can get CSV format like below screenshot:

screenshot of wanted table

[image]

Any Help will appreciate.

Comment: I cannot see any attached screenshots or output.. =(

Comment: Besides the screenshot is an excel sheet. Not a csv.

Comment: @lub0v I edited the post, now the screenshot links are available

Comment: @Jonathan They are CSV formatted, I manually corrected column sizes for being more readable.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `my_dict`?

Comment: `writer.writerow([''] + row)` might be a _really_ crude way to fix this. You haven't given much info.

Comment: @Alexander sure. {'Sep 23': 'Guatemala, Guatemala', 'Sep 29': 'Charlotte, NC', 'Sep 30': 'Fort Worth, TX', 'Oct 06': 'Los Angeles, CA', 'Oct 07': 'San Diego, CA'}

Comment: @roganjosh I'm getting error --->>>
   writer.writerow([''] + row)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Comment: `writer.writerow([''] + list(row))` then. Now at least we know you have a tuple :)

Comment: @roganjosh thank you very much, so before I can't understand what the errors means

Comment: Concatenate is basically "join together". Try: `a = [1, 2]`, `b = [3, 4]`, `c = a + b`... `print(c)` gives `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You had a mixed type before; this works with two lists but, in your case, you had a list and a tuple. My comment was basically giving you a way to give an empty value in your list, such  that it would push all items to the right when you wrote it to a CSV and leave the "Users" column empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
user = ""
with open('my.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('Users','Date','Location'))
    for date, location in my_dict.items():
        writer.writerow(user, date, location)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

csv = """
Users,Date,Location
23-sep,Guatemala-Guatemala,"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))

df.columns = np.roll(df.columns,-1) #shift columns
df = df[np.roll(df.columns,1)] # use previous order

df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Or with a file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

df.columns = np.roll(df.columns,-1) #shift columns
df = df[np.roll(df.columns,1)] # use previous order

df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```